# How to apply low level const to a template variable. I am trying to write a const_cast implementation

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

How do I make this `static_assert` pass in my failing code? I tried all permutations of `const` around `T` but I am not able to get `const int *`. Compiler always interprets it as `int * const`.

```
template <class T>
union const_cast_impl {

    using CT =  const T;
    static_assert(std::is_same<CT,const int *>::value, "CT is not const int*");

    T data;
    CT cdata;

    const_cast_impl(CT ptr):cdata(ptr){}

    operator T(){
        return data;
    }
};

int main(){
    int a = 2;
    const int *ptr = &a;
    int *ptr2 = const_cast_impl<int *>(ptr);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`std::conditional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) to handle pointer types correctly.

```
using CT = typename std::conditional<
                std::is_pointer<T>::value,
                typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type const *,
                T const
            >::type;
static_assert(std::is_same<CT,const int *>::value, "CT is not const int*");
```

Comment: Though only this part will work:
`using CT = typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type const *;`
Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: @mohit if you know `T` is a pointer, write a `T*` specialization instead of a `T` one...

Comment: @Mohit Didn't realize `T` was always a pointer. In that case, you should write a specialization as Yakk says, see the "Possible Implementation" section of [`remove_pointer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pointer) for an example.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, you could write a type trait that is specialized for pointers:

```
template <class T> struct const_qualify     { using type = T const; };
template <class T> struct const_qualify<T*> { using type = T const*; };
template <class T> struct const_qualify<T&> { using type = T const&; };
```

And then:

```
using CT = typename const_qualify<T>::type;
```

The reference specialization isn't really useful in this case, since you can't stick a reference in a union, but is there for completeness.